# Big Query Data Expiration

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have been collecting data in `BigQuery` for analysis purposes. However, the size of the data is growing and I only need 2 weeks of recent data. I wanted to erase data that is not used. I did some research and I found out that there is an expiration option for partitioned data.

**Current setup:**

My table is a partitioned table
I use a Lambda Function with a code similar to this in order to put data into the table (I have tried adding timePartitioning option, but it didn't work so that's why I am asking on stackoverflow if anyone knows)

```
wait bq
      .dataset("dataset name")
      .table('tablename' + '$' + partitionTime)
      .load( filename, {
        sourceFormat: 'CSV',
        schema,
        skipLeadingRows: 1, 
        timePartitioning: {
           expirationMs: "300000"
        }
      });
```

Where partitionTime is in the format YYYYMMDD (this places the data inserted into that partition)

Thank you for all your comments and taking time to read my trouble :) 
Have a nice day.

Comment: Can you provide more information? I would like to know which language you are using in your lambda (maybe JavaScript). Can you explain your workflow?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/Table.html#load), the function `load` accepts three parameters:

> 1. source (needed)
> 2. metadata (optional)
> 3. callback (optional)

The options that you need can be set in the `metadata` parameter. In the link provided above you can also notice that the `BigQuery SDK` uses API calls to perform the given operations.
In this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/insert) and in the printscreen bellow, you can see how to build a correct API call for `BigQuery`

[image]

In the field `timePartitioning` you can add [DAY](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.TimePartitioningType.html#google.cloud.bigquery.table.TimePartitioningType) as your tipe of partitioning and your expiration time in miliseconds.

In the end, your code would have a small change:

```
 wait bq
      .dataset("dataset name")
      .table('tablename')
      .load( filename, {
        sourceFormat: 'CSV',
        schema,
        skipLeadingRows: 1, 
        timePartitioning: {
           type: "DAY",
           expirationMs: "300000"
        }
      });
```

I hope it helps